# Administrator account can not be disabled

Tags: windows, windows-10

I noticed, that the integrated administrator account on windows 10 is always activated when I switch on my laptop.

I tried switching it off permanently with the `net user` command, but after a restart ist is active again and prompted as a user to log in.

Could this behavior be caused by a software or any misconfiguration in the settings?

Edit:
The administrator account is not available directly after I deactivate it. Only after a restart.

Comment: Are you using an admin account to disable the Administrator account?

Comment: @studiohack yes I am. I used the cmd in administrator mode and it says that the task was successfull.

Comment: Please provide the exact command your using.

Comment: @Ramhound net user Administrator /active:no

Comment: Right Click on Computer (that icon) and select Manage. Then expand Local Users and Groups, click on Users. In the right hand window, click on the Built In Administrator account, Properties, and ensure Disabled has been selected. That should work if otherwise the computer is working properly.

Comment: The built-in Administrator account on all recent versions of Windows is disabled by default.  This is especially true for Windows 10, as no version of Windows 10, has it enabled by default.  Are you connected to a Active Directory domain?

Comment: Yes I know that. I was responding to the question posted.

Comment: @Ramhound you mean a company domain? No, I'm not. I connected this device to my windows account, but I have done this several times before and had no issues.

Comment: @John I'm thankfully for any hint that might help :)

Comment: @John - I didn’t direct my last comment to you but the author.

Comment: @AndiLeni - What version of Windows 10 are you running?

Comment: @Ramhound it's 1909

Comment: If you have not been able to turn off the Administrative account like you wish to do, open, in Windows 10 Professional, Administative Tools and goto and open "Local Security Policy" there you should find, under Local Policies -> Security Options -> __Accounts: Administrator account status__. When Ramhound asked which version, I think he meant Windows 10 Professional or Home.

Comment: @vssher I just have the home edition

Comment: Try this Open a command prompt with administrative permissions and type __net user Administrator /active:no__ (yes to turn it on again) See this Shawn Brink's page at Ten Forums https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2969-enable-disable-elevated-administrator-account-windows-10-a.html  Hope I helped ;p)